# Thesis writing - should I write "will be discussed later" or "as was discussed previously"

Tags: thesis

I am writing my MD thesis, which is about therapy for MS, and some drugs come up in more than one specific subchapter. Should I discuss them in detail in the first subchapter they come up in, or should I discuss them in the last chapter they come up in?

Comment: You could also think about a specific section/subchapter for discussing all of them.

Comment: A rule of thumb I like is: use forward references sparingly if at all (i.e., structure the paper so they are rarely if ever needed).

Answer (score 16):

The answer varies: Readers will sometimes expect introduction there-and-then, in others they'll expect a delay, some readers will be divided. Regardless, generally avoid *will be discussed later* and *as was discussed previously*, use section references to guide the reader.

Comment: I couldn't agree more about section references. Information is not linear. You want to resist the urge to have your thesis tell a story, where more information is revealed as you work your way through it, or where you need to remember what you'd previously read.

Comment: @McHobbes "You want to resist the urge to have your thesis tell a story"  That's surprising advice to me as I would advise my students that is exactly what they should be doing. (Of course, this could just be a different understanding of what "tell a story" means.)

Comment: @MichaelMior Telling a story is a good thing, but having a thesis or paper read like a mystery novel isn't.

Comment: @MichaelMior Of course, different people could have different preferences and, as you suggested, our preferential differences may be a matter of our individual understandings of what "tell a story" means. But, from my standpoint, if I wanted to glean the information that a thesis or paper is meant to portray, I don't want to be left wondering until a climax where the pieces finally fall into place. That's essentially the point I'm trying to make.

Comment: +1. Forward references should be *specific* and *limited to where they're really needed. Some basic introduction is probably required at the first mention, but as little as possible so as not to disrupt the flow.  A (sub-)section reference works well, page is probably excessive. LaTeX makes it easy!

Comment: @McHobbes Agreed. When I talk about telling a story, there should be significant spoilers :)

Answer (score 11):

I tend to find forward and backward references that provide more context to be useful, such as: "Section 4.3 presents experiments that show that mint chocolate chip ice cream significantly reduces MS symptoms" and "This chapter presents experiments, as motivated by the discussion in Section 1.2, on the effect of mint chocolate chip ice cream on MS"

Answer (score 4):

Several thoughts.

- Think about who might read your thesis, and why. Put yourself in
  their frame of mind. Then structure your thesis the way you would
  like to encounter it.
- Do tell a story - the one that's right for that reader.
- Do use section number references rather than just "earlier" or
  "later".
- If you can look at other theses in your program you can see what they
  do.
- Ask your advisor.
- Don't worry too much about this. Whatever you do will be OK.